# mvn package, cannot find source for spark.components.SkinnableContainer

Tags: java, actionscript-3, maven, pom.xml

use maven to compile a project.
when i execute "mvn package",

```
Error "can not find source for spark.components.SkinnableContainer"
```

i have configure the "spark" dependency in project pom.xml,here is the code,is there some wrong? How to solve the issue?

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
```

and i can not find any related source of "spark.components" in [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/)

after the dependency configuration,it is still wrong,do i not find the right repository or the right version?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified wrong dependency. This class "spark.components.SkinnableContainer" does not exist in jar spark-core-1.0.jar.

You can verify on -
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sparkjava/spark-core/1.0